# Batch file - Is there a way to check if hardware is enabled/disabled before continuing code?

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, cmd.exe

I'm currently using this subscript (as part of a larger start-up script):

```
@echo off
echo *** Enabling NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 with Max-Q Design ***
devmanview.exe /enable "NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 with Max-Q Design"
echo *** Done ***
taskkill /IM cmd.exe
```

As it takes a little time to complete, do you know if there's a way to check if 'NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 with Max-Q Design' is already enabled before continuing onto 'devmanview.exe /enable "NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 with Max-Q Design"'?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can check if the device is already enabled by using the devmanview.exe utility with the /list_devices option. This will list all the devices in the Device Manager, along with their current status (enabled or disabled).

You can then use a loop to search through the list of devices and check if the device you are interested in is already enabled. Here is an example of how you can do this using the findstr command to search for the device name in the list of devices:

```
@echo off

rem Check if the device is already enabled
devmanview.exe /list_devices > devices.txt

if not findstr /I "NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 with Max-Q Design" devices.txt goto enable_device

echo *** NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 with Max-Q Design is already enabled ***
goto end

:enable_device
echo *** Enabling NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 with Max-Q Design ***
devmanview.exe /enable "NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 with Max-Q Design"
echo *** Done ***

:end
taskkill /IM cmd.exe
```

This script will check if the device is already enabled, and if it is not, it will enable it. If the device is already enabled, it will print a message indicating that the device is already enabled and then exit.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!
When I run the script though, it seems to just close the cmd window immediately and doesn't re-enable the graphics card...

Comment: Just played around with it some more and I think the script needs admin rights to execute correctly. When it does though, it seems to just open a devmanview window and then the script gets stuck.